# Azure AD User management delegation

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD to create users, groups for an application that sits outside of Azure AD (hosted internally)

I want the ability to delegate the user management to an admin of that application (create users, assign groups etc)

I can see that in the Premium Azure AD subscription you can create AD users that have access to the WAAD Access Panel (myapps.microsoft.com) and they can see groups, you can assign users to groups and view/action approval requests

There however doesnt look like there is any way to create users through this interface which is odd. Seems like it should be there if the user has "User Management" role.

Is there any other way to provide basic level user management delegation to an application admin?

The only other way I can see is for a user admin to create a whole new azure subscription (but part of same tenant) and go through the management portal - which is not ideal because they have access to other Azure resources (creating instances, db etc). I only need the admin to be able to access user management of AD

I know I can create another application and use the Graph API but this might be re-inventing the wheel if Azure AD already has something like this.

Comment: no, there is no such feature. Beyond the User/Group management in Azure Management Portal and User / Group management in Office365 Admin Portal. Azure Graph API **is** the way to go for your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with your current setup by using the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Using the [Azure AD Graph API Client library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/12/12/announcing-azure-ad-graph-api-client-library-2-0.aspx) as a base and create a local area in your application, where given Administrator user for your application can manage users and groups in the Azure AD via the Graph API.

There is a good sample on [how to use Graph API with .NET](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet) on the [GitHub sample pages for AD](https://github.com/AzureADSamples).

Comment: while I dont disagree with you, I was hoping there was some sort of inbuilt Azure thing for this - if I went down the Graph API path it would mean a fair bit of development which im trying to avoid. If Azure already has this sort of functionality it would save alot of time and effort

Comment: Then go for Premium instead of asking for free lunch!

Comment: I signed up for premium and it still isnt quite what im after - I have rephrased question because i wasnt quite clear the first time around

Comment: Marty - trying to understand what you need here.  Is it another role that you can delegate user management capabilities to?  If so, one such in-built role already exists in Azure AD (user admin) - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn468213.aspx.

Comment: the problem is that this role doesnt even have a user add interface in the WAAD Access Panel - they need to login to the manage interface which has other stuff outside of AD which is not ideal - if you know of another interface to add users please let me know :)

Comment: no, there is no another user management interface beside the two I already mentioned - Active Directory section in Azure Management Portal and Admin Portal of Office 365.

Comment: Hey Marty - it seems like what you are asking for is either some kind of self service user management portal, similar to self service group management.  Not sure about self service for user management - really that's an admin task, or I guess it could go through a workflow.  In any case the aforementioned portals are your only options for now.  Is there an issue with using these portals?  Alternatively your delegated admin could user Azure AD Powershell for user management.